# Negative Binomial and Geometric Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, actuarial-science

So this is the problem I'm dealing with.

An actuary has determined that the number of claims per month can take any number
0, 1, 2, 3,... and follows a negative binomial distribution with mean 3 and variance 12. Calculate the probability that the number of claims is at least three but less than six.

So by using some properties of the negative binomial we can derive that p=0.25, and r=1. It was my understanding that a geometric distribution is just a negative binomial distribution with r=1. Given this I tried using the pmf for geometric distribution and got the wrong answer. Can someone explain to me what is going on here.

Comment: Which definition of the neg. bin. distribution have you used and what have you calculated? Holding back information is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since the number of claims $X\sim \text{Geometric}(\frac 14)$, the desired porbability is $P(X=3)+P(X=4)+P(X=5)=\left(\frac 34\right)^3\frac 14+\left(\frac 34\right)^4\frac 14+\left(\frac 34\right)^5\frac 14=0.2438965$

Comment: What I was thinking was that X=3 would be 'three trials until first success' meaning 'two failures and one success" however, the random variable X is defined as just # of claims. I think this makes sense now.

Comment: @user8083 Yes, in fact the total number of trials is $X+1$, e.g. the number of claims plus 1. $X$ is considered the number of failures, which is considered the number of claims. And the sole success is considered a not-claim. u gonna consider upvoting/accepting?

Answer (score 0):

There are too many ways to parameterize the negative binomial, but using Klugman-Panjer-Wilmott as most US actuaries do, you can write it as:

$$
{r+k-1\choose k}\frac{\beta^k}{\left(1+\beta\right)^{r+k}}
$$

where the mean is $r\beta$ and the variance is $r\beta(1+\beta)$.

So if $r\beta = 3$ and $r\beta(1+\beta) = 12$ then $(1+\beta) = 4$ so $\beta = 3$ and $r = 1$. Now solve for $P(k \in {3, 4, 5})$